# Deny access to one specific folder in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to deny users from accessing the `site/includes` folder by manipulating the URL.

I don't know if I have to deny everything and manually make individual exceptions to allow, if I can just deny this one folder, or if there's a rewrite function that can be used.

Specific example: I don't want to see the directory files by typing in `localhost/site/includes` into the URL.

Comment: just to disallow listing directories write `Options -Indexes` in .htaccess file located in root folder

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Create `site/includes/.htaccess` file and add this line:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: Hey!! anubhava I've used this to disable direct access to my api files inside /api folder but now all webservice call sending 403 forbidden status .. I just want to block access when someone access it from browser.

Comment: For a webserver there is no real difference between requests between browser and non-browser.

Comment: I use of nginx and I can not use of `.htaccess`. so, how can I do that without `.htaccess` ? thanks

Comment: How can I access the files of folder/sub folder if I deny from all? The files into folder/sub folder gives 404 error.

Comment: `Deny from all` won't give 404 but 403. You can still access file/folders using PHP/Perl etc but not using a web request. You can open a new question if that didn't answer your query.

Comment: You didn't even show where to insert the directive and how the file should look like.

Comment: All the necessary information is already there in answer. As per OP it was needed in `site/includes/.htaccess`

Comment: Note that if you want to use this, apache should allow it. In the site config `<Directory>`, you would need to have at least `AllowOverride Limit`.

Answer (score 92):

You can also deny access to a folder using `RedirectMatch`

Add the following line to htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/?$
```

This will return a `403 forbidden` error for the folder ie : `http://example.com/folder/` but it doest block access to files and folders inside that folder, if you want to block everything inside the folder then just change the regex pattern to `^/folder/.*$` .

Another option is `mod-rewrite`
If `url-rewrting-module` is enabled you can use something like the following in `root/.htaccss` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^folder/?$ - [F,L]
```

This will internally map a request for the `folder` to `forbidden` error page.

Comment: With Apache 2.22 the best solution is the first one: RedirectMatch.....

Comment: Much prefer this answer, rather than creating multiple `.htaccess` files in every directory that I need to deny access for.

Comment: this is a much better answer than the one marked as correct, seriously

Comment: @user151496 That's debatable. The "accepted" answer is arguably more secure since the mod_alias (or mod_rewrite) directives used here in the root are more easily overridden (even accidentally).

Answer (score 50):

In an `.htaccess` file you need to use

```
Deny from  all
```

Put this in `site/includes/.htaccess` to make it specific to the `includes` directory

If you just wish to disallow a listing of directory files you can use

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Is this recursive?

Comment: @Abdillah Yes it is

Comment: i get an "internal server error 500" if i just add `Options -Indexes` to the bottom of the page? @OliverMGrech

Comment: Check if anything else in your htaccess is causing the server error. Apache's error log file might tell you what's missing or what's wrong

Answer (score 25):

We will set the directory to be very secure, denying access for all file types. Below is the code you want to insert into the .htaccess file.

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all
```

Since we have now set the security, we now want to allow access to our desired file types. To do that, add the code below to the .htaccess file under the security code you just inserted.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|php)$">
Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

your final `.htaccess` file will look like

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all 

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|php)$">
Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Source from [Allow access to specific file types in a protected directory](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/access-specific-filetype)

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of headache. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a .htaccess file for the folder, wich should have denied access with

```
Deny from  all
```

or you can redirect to a custom 404 page

```
Redirect /includes/ 404.html
```

Answer (score 9):

Just put .htaccess into the folder you want to restrict

```
## no access to this folder

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Source: [MantisBT](https://github.com/mantisbt/mantisbt) sources.

Answer (score 6):

On Apache 2.4 you can use an Apache `<If>` expression in the root `.htaccess` file to block direct access to this specific subdirectory and everything within it.

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/site/includes($|/)#">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Comment: this is what i have been looking

Answer (score 4):

Creating index.php, index.html, index.htm is not secure. Becuse, anyone can get access on your files within specified directory by guessing files name. E.g.: http://yoursite.com/includes/file.dat
So, recommended method is creating a .htaccess file to deny all visitors ;). Have fun !!

Answer (score 4):

You can also put this `IndexIgnore *`  at your root .htaccess file to disable file listing of all of your website directories including sub-dir

Comment: This does not disable file listing, but tells the autoindexer to ignore all files when constructing the index. To disable file listing, you'd use `Options -Indexes`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this dynamically that way:

```
mkdir($dirname);
@touch($dirname . "/.htaccess");
  $f = fopen($dirname . "/.htaccess", "w");
  fwrite($f, "deny from all");
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons which I did not understand, creating folder/.htaccess and adding Deny from All failed to work for me. I don't know why, it seemed simple but didn't work, adding RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/.*$ to the root htaccess worked instead.

Comment: Apache server must be configured to support local .htaccess files in subdirectories. If it is not, creating local files will have no effect, obviously.