# How to prohibit access to my site directory?

Tags: php, html, apache

I have this website, example.com, and I just discovered that I can access my folders through the URL (for example, I can access the img folder using a web browser by going to http://example.com/img ). It's crazy! I'm sorry, I can't even search for the proper term in Google/StackOverflow because I don't know what it's called or what the proper term is. Also, I am using tags generously because I'm not sure what categories this would fall under.

Comment: If a folder is under the web root, and isn't protected by an [.htaccess file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess) or equivalent, then it is publicly accessible

Answer (score 1):

put `Options -Indexes` in your .htaccess to prevent directory listing
... or `deny from all` if you want to restrict access to files

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to a file named `.htaccess`  in the root of your site with the following line

```
Options -Indexes
```

It will prevent Apache from listing the contents of the directories to your visitors and should still allow you to reference files within them (ie images) in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either two ways. First is to create an `index.html` file and store it in the directory, so that whenever anyone tries to navigate that directory through the URL he'll see the `index.html` page. And the second option would be to create a .htaccess file inside the directory and place this line of code inside it: `Options -Indexes`. I would recommend adding a 404 Not Found page with header informations, like what most of the websites are already doing.