# PHP - how to protect the uploaded files directory

Tags: php, apache, centos

i have a directory `public/1` where all the PDF, CSV files get uploaded by end users and they are very confidential files.

now the url is publicly exposed such as: http://www.example.com/1

how can i protect that specific URL not being exposed to public network?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess)

Comment: *Don't* put those files into a publicly accessible web hosted folder...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with htaccess. Create a file named .htaccess with following content. Make sure to replace uploaddir with correct directory name.

```
<Directory "uploaddir/">
deny from all
</Directory>
```

Also I suggest you to use [encryption](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) before storing the files. So If someone managed to download the file he can't use it.

Comment: so i put the .htaccess file under the folder /var/www/html/stackoverflow.com/public/1 ?

Comment: Yes. Make sure to replace uploaddir with correct dir name.

Answer (score 2):

Close it by using .htaccess ?

Add it to robots.txt so it doesnt get indexed ?

Add a index.html to it so it isnt a open dir ?

Comment: 2 and 3 are nowhere near a good enough measure to *protect sensitive files*.

Comment: but its very recommended to do :)

Comment: If you configure your web server to return a 404 or 403 for anything in that folder, or not put those files on the web in the first place, you don't need a robots.txt or index.html.