# Base directory of my website is accessible and that is public, how to hide from public?

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite new in Laravel PHP framework. I had a project and successfully completed and right now it's in production (online sever). but today I saw that everyone can access the base directory of site by just adding a slash to search string and folder name.

For example, if someone type like this

> www.mywebsite.com

the page is working properly and all user access are working.

but when someone type like this

> www.mywebsite.com/pages

They can access all my pages stored in the folder. All php files which are secrete and must not be viewed publicly. Actually I am storing some pages in the folder (pages).

This is a screen shot. Displaying files in the directory which is not public.

[image]

I know, I am missing a small thing, but I don't know how to get that.

Comment: If you're using Laravel, the only php file you should have in public is index.php.  Other than that, you're supposed to use routes, controllers, and views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny access to one specific folder in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess)

Comment: What's in your `public/.htaccess`?

Comment: this is my public/.htaccess content 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a 404.blade.php file in your resource/views/errors folder

if it does not work then stop Auto Directory Index from your hosting.

You can try this .htaccess to prevent Auto Index

```
IndexIgnore *
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

where is you index.php file? put index.php inside the public folder. also .htaccess should be there too with appropriate settings.

Comment: index.php is inside public folder and .htaccess is 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>