# how to set htaccess in laravel subfolder?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

i have a folder that name is admin in root of laravel project.and there is js, css, images and fonts in that folder.Now how can i deny other's to access that folder in laravel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny access to one specific folder in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess)

Comment: i can't do it with these are!!!

Answer (score 0):

i solve it with this code in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] //this line is for admin folder access limitation
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```