# How to deny access to multiple folders using one .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have multiple folders on my website and one `.htaccess` in the root of the site. I want to deny access to some of them using `htaccess`. I found this post:

[Deny access to one specific folder in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19118482/5104748)

Its solution is creating `.htaccess` file in target folder but I want to do this work using one `.htaccess`. I want to deny access to target folders using one `.htaccess` in the root of the site.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deny access to subfolders from root lavel htaccess, you can use the following RewriteRules :

```
RewriteRule ^folderA/$ - [R=403,L]
RewriteRule ^folderB/$ - [R=403,L]
```

The rules will return a 403 forbidden error if /folderA/ and /folderB is requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/ - [F]
RewriteRule ^someotherfolder/ - [F]
# you can also use RegEx:
RewriteRule ^folder([0-9]+)/ - [F]
```