# Regex to block url in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url, url-pattern

I want to block access to urls that have excess characters at its end.

E.g. I want nginx to block requests to `https://www.example.com/url-pattern/amp/extra-chars/more-extra`

but want it to allow `https://www.example.com/url-pattern/amp` or `https://www.example.com/url-pattern/amp/`

Will this work?

```
location .*\/amp\/. {
   deny all
}
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it myself. If anyone is looking for the same solution

```
location ~* /amp/. {
 deny all;
}
```

Comment: Where was this applied? Please, Thanks

Comment: You can apply it to your nginx config files where location rules are specified.

Comment: Little Lebowski, Thank you.

Comment: i want rule, if someone enter "/amp/123" it should return 403, everything except "/amp/" shoud return 403

Comment: oh you saved my day, thank you !