# Laravel - Not Found - The requested resource /control was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hi everyone I need a solution with laravel project when I try open backend admin with /control its giving me an error "Not Found - The requested resource /control was not found on this server."

When I change the name "/control" to anything like "/control5" or something its working fine but the problem is I use /control at views and other! I am new to laravel I didn't know what the problem was? please help me out with this!

Web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/about', [App\Http\Controllers\AboutController::class,'about']);
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController::class,'index']);
Route::get('/listing', [App\Http\Controllers\ListingPageController::class,'index']);
Route::get('/details', [App\Http\Controllers\DetailsPageController::class,'index']);
Route::group(['prefix' => 'control','middleware' => 'auth'],function(){
   Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\DashboardController::class,'index'])->name('control');
   //Pages
   Route::get('/pages', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\PagesController::class,'index']);
   Route::get('/pages/add', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\PagesController::class,'create']);
   Route::get('/pages/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\PagesController::class,'edit']);
});
```

DashboardController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Control;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('control.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any resource route in your web.php , maybe you forget to create.

Comment: its prefix /control

Comment: the first one is for homepage and second one is for backend 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and http://127.0.0.1:8000/control

Comment: Can you share your route list , generated with `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: @sta i have a resources/views/control

Comment: @MuditGulgulia GET|HEAD| / | App\Http\Controllers\HomePageController@index | web
GET|HEAD| about | App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@about | web
GET|HEAD| control | control | App\Http\Controllers\Control\DashboardController@index | web auth
GET|HEAD| control/genres | App\Http\Controllers\Control\GenresController@index | web auth
GET|HEAD| control/genres/create | App\Http\Controllers\Control\GenresController@create | web auth
DELETE| control/genres/delete/{id} | genres-delete | App\Http\Controllers\Control\GenresController@destroy | web auth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because, you have a folder named `control` on `/public` folder. That error occurs when you create a folder in the public folder with the same name as your route so please change the name of the folder you have put in the public folder so that it has a different name from your route this will probably solve your error

Comment: oh yes that was the issue! is there any way that i change its without change the name beacuse i had use that name for style and script in all views

Comment: @Watch-Online.in I am not sure but may be htaccess can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118529/4575350 or try this one on your public root `.htaccess` 
 file https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825743/4575350

Comment: thanks u bro! for that help I had search all around for this! :)