# How can I deploy Code Igniter 4 using git outside of public_html - Hostinger

Tags: git, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting, codeigniter-4

I would like to deploy the backend of my project outside of public_html, while the public files are on public_html. I don't have much trouble when uploading the files manually to the file manager, but it's a hassle for me to update them manually for every change on my git repository. So I wanted to use the deployment feature of Hostinger via git to upload them automatically.

I've made two Git repositories for my project, one for front-end (public) and one for backend

From the CPanel advance->git Create Repository Form, I manage to deploy my public files to the public_html folder. For the backend, I tried setting the directory field with the value of `../target_folder`, assuming that the root folder is public_html. But I'm receiving an error message stating that the directory is invalid.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got a reply from the Hostinger support team. Unfortunately, they do not support git deployment outside of public_html.

My workaround for the backend is to deploy it on public_html in a subfolder with [.htaccess to restrict users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess). Though it may not be the best solution for other web-hosting services.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access in your hosting plan then you can create a new ssh key and do it manually by using

```
git clone git@github.com:[github-name]/[repo-name].git /path/to/your/dir
```

then you can do

```
git pull
```

as usual for evey push to your central repo. You can also try to automate things using cronjobs

**I'm sorry this is a complete answer. I dont have enough reputation to comment. I hope this will be helpful to someone**