# is the password for my database in my config.php not being hashed okay?

Tags: php, mysql

I am implementing a crypto payment script that a developer has made for me, and am going through it to make sure its all good. I have a question however, in the config.php the admin password to access the admin panel is fine as it is hashed, however the Database password to mySQL is not, I asked him about it and he said that is how it works and is correct, just looking if there is any security flaws with this, the database and website are hosted on the same server.

```
define('X_USER', 'test123');
define('X_PASSWORD', 'HASHED PASSWORD');
define('X_DB_NAME', 'Test1');
define('X_DB_USER', 'Test1user');
define('X_DB_PASSWORD', 'test12345678');
define('X_DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('X_DB_PORT', '3306');
define('X_URL', 'mywebsite.com');
```

as you can see in the above code, the DB password test12345678 is not hashed.

Comment: It's always like that. It needs to use the password to log into the database, so it can't be hashed. Admin password only needs to be validated so it can be hashed.

Comment: You usually send the plaintext password to mysql, which then checks against the hashed version. As long as you securely store the password (keep it in a PHP file, ideally store it out of webroot), you should be okay.

Comment: This might be related to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432545/how-to-safely-store-a-password-inside-php-code

Comment: thanks everyone just wanted to make sure. also quick question is there any way to password protect a directory while also allowing it function on the front end? I  tried however when the admin panel is password protected it does not function on the frontend for functions that my users do. password protected as in the files themselves.

Comment: The main reason I am so worried and want the security perfect is that I have my Crypto addresses in the SQL database and the admin panel, and want to make sure neither a hacker can change it to theres or change it when it is being transmitted from my server to the user. I already am using a non obvious admin panel url, olfdsj921rf0d12j.mywebsite.com/adsmi21i021   something like that, is there anything else I can do to further the security?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question, not hidden in the comment section